# django + ngnix, serving media files

Tags: python, django, server, django-staticfiles

i show you directly my code:

i handle the link `ewayApp/media/{stuff}` with django:

```
urls.py:

path('ewayApp/media/<str:media_url_1>/<str:media_url_2>/<str:media_url_3>',course.getMedia),
```

the handler:

```
course.py:

def getMedia(request, media_url_1, media_url_2, media_url_3):
    ...some stuff...     
    url = '/protected/' + media_url_1+'/'+media_url_2+'/'+media_url_3
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url
    return response
```

and i'm sure going for the first link i pass through this function because i have some prints along the function.

my ngnix settings:

```
location ~ / {

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;


    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location  ^~ /protected/ {
    internal;
    alias path/to/media/media/;
}
```

So, the django server runs on 127.0.0.1:8080 and ngnix proxies all the requests there. when accessing these media files if i go straight to the link [https://website.com/ewayApp/media/{stuff}](https://website.com/ewayApp/media/%7Bstuff%7D) ngnix returns me back 404 error not found. I checked if the media are stored in `path/to/media/media/`, and they are, but obviously in subdirectories with `media_url_1`, `media_url_1` ... that are specified in `{stuff}`

How to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Just to tell you that effectivly the link is right because if i turn the debug flag of django to True, the media files are displayed, so everything is stored in the right place and the link is right too, but somhow i can't display with this accel-redirect + ngnix

Solved:

as suggested by Mh Eftekhari i did something similar to what he answered but adding the '^~', my solution for ngnix setting:

```
location  ^~/protected/ {
    internal;

    alias /path/to/media/media;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

}

location ~ / {

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    ##Use the domain.tld here.
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Comment: Why did you use the [tag:apache] tag for a nginx question?

Answer (score 1):

change your configuration to this

```
       location /protected{
                alias path/to/media/media/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
```

Comment: ok ,  i will try and i will tell you if it works :). Nope it does not work

Comment: can you send me access same any desk.

Comment: mh no sorry i can't

Comment: you change your configuration to this?
location ~ / {

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;


    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

       location /protected{
                alias path/to/media/media/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }

and you cannot access to file?

Comment: activate your nginx log and send it to me

Comment: man, now it's working. You are my saver. it didn't worked but then i changed to : location  ^~/protected/ {
 internal;

 alias /path/to/media/media/;
 try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

}

location ~ / {

 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

 ##Use the domain.tld here.
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}, so i added the ^~ and it worked thanks a lot man. +1 for you. ah i ave no reputtation for your +1, sorry :(